# How do I Count the number of user inputs in this java code?

Tags: java

So far I have,

```
package randomnumberguessinggame;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomNumberGuessingGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     int secretNumber;
        secretNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 999 + 1);

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess;
        int count = 0;
        do {
              System.out.print("Enter a guess: (1-1000) ");
              guess = keyboard.nextInt();
              System.out.println("Your guess is " + guess);
              if (guess == secretNumber)
                    System.out.println("Your guess is correct. Congratulations!");

              else if (guess < secretNumber)
                    System.out.println("Your guess is smaller than the secret number.");

              else if (guess > secretNumber)
                    System.out.println("Your guess is greater than the secret number.");

        } while (guess != secretNumber);                         
    }
}
```

This code works but I need to know how to count the number of user inputs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: update count as count++ inside while . The number of user inputs would be equals to count-1 when you exit the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one incrementation into your do while loop `count = count + 1;` as the last command. It would work anywhere in the do loop, but it's logical to put it after the input was processed.

Then add a line `System.out.println("Number of guesses:"+count);` under your loop.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `count++` under `guess = keyboard.nextInt();`